# Wrong body width in Linux Firefox

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox

I try to get body width in Linux Firefox.

document.body.scrollWidth is equal to width which I can see in firefox window.

So when I changed window size, document.body.scrollWidth is changed.

But in Google Chrome, It is equal to body width.

My Firefox version is 6.0.

How can I get body width in Firefox/Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollwidth `scrollWidth` on the `<body>` returns the 'window size' (or more precisely the actual width of the body box) in standards mode and the document content width in quirks mode (item 3 in the list).

It sounds like your page is in standards mode.  In which case `document.documentElement.scrollWidth` should do what you wan (item 2 in the list).

Comment: Document you linked help me a lot. Sorry for late reply and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for offsetWidth which computes the width of the contents of the body.

Comment: I already check odcument.body.offsetWidth and document.body.clientWidth but they also depend on firefox window size.